# Randomly sample lines retaining commented header lines

Tags: bash, random

I'm attempting to randomly sample lines from a (large) file, while always retaining a set of "header lines". Header lines are always at the top of the file and unlike any other lines, begin with a #.

The actual file format I'm dealing with is a [VCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_Call_Format), but I've kept the question general

Requirements:

- Output all header lines (identified by a # at line start)
- The command / script should (have the option to) read from STDIN
- The command / script should output to STDOUT

For example, consider the following sample file (file.in):

```
#blah de blah
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

An example output (file.out) would be:

```
#blah de blah
10
2
5
3
4
```

I have a working solution (in this case selecting 5 non-header lines at random) using bash. It is capable of reading from STDIN (I can cat the contents of file.in into the rest of the command) however it writes to a named file rather than STDOUT:

```
cat file.in | tee >(awk '$1 =~ /^#/' > file.out) | awk '$1 !~ /^#/' | shuf -n 5 >> file.out
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) (thanks Tom Fenech), both commands are seen as files.
Then using cat we can concatenate these "files" together and output to STDOUT.

```
cat <(awk '/^#/' file) <(awk '!/^#/' file | shuf -n 10)
```

#### Input

```
#blah de blah
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

#### Output

```
#blah de blah
1
9
8
4
7
2
3
10
6
5
```

Comment: It's called [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution)

Comment: That's great! Is there a way to pipe into this though? Can "file" be "STDIN"?

Comment: @wannymahoots Probably.How/what do you want to pipe in ?

Comment: @TomFenech Cheers, i kept thinking command substitution and just couldn't find it!

Comment: No problem, as you probably already know, command substitution allows you to use the output of a command as a variable, whereas process substitution allows you to use it as a file descriptor.

Comment: How unusual - a *useful* use of `cat`.

Comment: @User112638726 I'd like the option of being able to pipe the file into the cat command. This doesn't appear to work as both commands are reading STDIN: `cat file | cat <(awk '/^#/') <(awk '!/^#/' | shuf -n 1)`

Comment: @wannymahoots oh well